# Sinatra Gem install error

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have been trying to install sinatra in a macbook running leopard system, and I am not able to do it.
I get the following error.

```
MacBook:rubygems-1.3.7 lakshmanan$ gem install sinatra
WARNING:  RubyGems 1.2+ index not found for:
http://rubygems.org/

RubyGems will revert to legacy indexes degrading performance.
Bulk updating Gem source index for: http://rubygems.org/
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `gems' for #<Array:0x101901008>
```

Please help. I reinstalled gems also. Still I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rubygems.org does not seem to be responding right now. Try again later. It's probably nothing on your end.